# Key navigation in advance data grid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am using advance data grid in my project and i have made a separate component for datagrid.
I have set the property 'selectionMode' to single cell.I am also using some text boxes in cells.Now I want when a user navigate through keyboard using UP,DOWN,LEFT or RIGHT arrow key and selected cell have textbox then at that time navigation stop if he/she press any key except mentioned above i.e. at that time focus would set to text box.And text boxes are managed in other file rather it(data grid component).Any one ??